# Correcting dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies

During the installation of a game, the package manager required some packages and after input of them, instead of installing them, it required as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-pc : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14)
 grub-pc-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14)
 grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.14)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After input the required command, didn't solved the problem. :(

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  grub-common
Suggested packages:
  multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
  grub-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 244 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1.705 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8.192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdbusmenu-glib4:amd64'     missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython2.7-dev:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libappindicator3-1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python2.7-dev' missing; assuming     package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libpython2.7-minimal:amd64' is missing final     newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Is it a recurrent issue?

Comment: Have you run out of disk space? (If you’re not sure, [edit] your question to show the output of `df -h`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to suggest using `aptitude` (instead of `apt-get`), somehow I found it better to solve dependency issues

What actually happened to you looks like some package problem:

`dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libpython2.7-minimal:amd64' is missing final     newline`

Most likely this causes your headaches.

Quickly googling this reveals:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/apt-get-dpkg-error-files-list-file-missing-final-newline-271118/

So lets try to remove this pkg from your system (it should be somewhere under `/var/cache/apt/` and then install it again.

I presume that package (somehow) broke already on your system.